# Chocolatey upgrade command is not working and is stuck on v0.10.15

Tags: window, chocolatey

My chco is not updating after entering choco upgrade chocolatey and is stuck on v0.10.15

```
PS C:\Users\> choco upgrade chocolatey
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Upgrading the following packages:
chocolatey
By upgrading you accept licenses for the packages.
chocolatey v2.2.2 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Did you know the proceeds of Pro (and some proceeds from other
 licensed editions) go into bettering the community infrastructure?
 Your support ensures an active community, keeps Chocolatey tip top,
 plus it nets you some awesome features!
 https://chocolatey.org/compare
PS C:\Users\> choco --version
0.10.15
```

Comment: > Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
> See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).  

Did you look in the log?

Comment: Hey yes thank you I just resolved the issue, it seem that that was another process refusing to let the update happened and was fixed by restarting the computer and running the choco upgrade cmd again.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out!

Comment: Upgrading to Chocolatey 2.x versions from anything other than 1.4.0 is not supported. See the upgrade doc at https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/upgrading-to-chocolatey-v2-v6